# JQuery and select2 - $ scope conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2-4

I am using `jQuery 2.1.3` min along with the `select2` plugin of jQuery in a spring mvc web application.

There has been an issue of `$'s` scope conflict I am facing with it.

Though all the ajax requests I am sending are written in a file called `home.jsp` under the `<script>` tag it shows they are sent through `select2` in firebug.

[image: conflict of select2]

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/views/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/views/js/custom/home.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/views/js/select2/js/select2.full.js"/>"></script>
```

This is the order in which I have included my js file. I feel like select2 causes havoc in my code. I am unable to figure out why?

Comment: Why don't you show the code in question where calls are made?

Comment: @KevinBrown: It worked!!!! I was using beta version, upgraded it to 4.0.0-rc.2 and everything is falling in place now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using an older version of Select2 4.0.0, most likely one of the betas.  In 4.0.0-beta.3, we stopped packaging jQuery in `select2.full.js` because it caused strange issues like this.